# A Smuggled List of S'S

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, anagram, crossword-clues

Smuggled this strange list from *[redacted]* 's place. Maybe he is making a puzzle. Who is the victim?

> - Scarlet covers
> - Swindler's imprecation
> - Sour disordered equipment
> - Smash journal
> - Sinful America
> - Surgeon oath
> - Storms carport

<sub>Working for [Generalist Countdown](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/generalist-countdown?cb=1) - [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram)</sub>

Comment: #6 = hippocratic?

Comment: @Randal'Thor sorry nope

Comment: #1 = rot13( evqqyrf )?

Comment: @aml sorry dont get what you mean. typo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What are the items on the list?

> Synonyms of the words on the list can be anagrammed to a tag on Puzzling SE plus one letter. For example: "Scarlet covers" are "red lids", which is an anagram of "riddle" plus "s". The complete list is:
>
>  Scarlet covers: *red lids* — **riddle** + **s**
>  Swindler's imprecation: *cheat's dammit* — **mathematics** + **d**
>  Sour disordered equipment: *acidic unglued tool* — **logical deduction** + **u**
>  Smash journal: *plow diary* — **wordplay** + **i**
>  Sinful America: *evil USA* — **visual** + **e**
>  Surgeon oath: *Dr vow* — **word** + **v**
>  Storms carport: *typhoons garage* — **steganography** + **o**

Who is the victim?

> If we assume that the third item is correct and that the second item yields an extra **d**, we can anagram the extra letters to [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi). (Thanks, jafe, for spotting that. I had a rather less convincing guess first.)

Comment: Ooh, nice find! For #2 I was thinking "conman's curse" but it doesn't seem to work. (Note also the OP's edits to the question, suggesting that the `'s` after swindler may not be needed.)

Comment: If the B is wrong, the missing letters could be DU...

Comment: Ok, I love anagrams, but no way would I have thought to do this. @OmegaKrypton this is brilliant. I am bookmarking this. I literally feel dumb looking at this puzzle.

Comment: there's no 's' in 'logical-deduction, so 'tools' is wrong.

Comment: @jafe Oh, that's kind of "bovious" in hindsight ...

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: Yes, it is obviously just "tool". (And with some imagination, "bungled" may become "unglued" to match jafe's suggestion.)

Comment: Pba qvf = pbvaf + q. V ernpurq guvf pbapyhfvba nsgre frrvat gur pbzzrag gung gur 'f znl abg or arrqrq va fjvaqyre'f

Comment: @JS1: Yes, that could be. That's not a tag I was aware of.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. It got a bit tedious towards the end. I guess it's not for nothing that indirect anagrams are frowned upon.

Comment: nice job! nailed it...