# Salt, pepper, herbs and spices

Tags: riddle, wordplay, anagram

> This puzzle is dedicated to an avid violinist.

**Who is the violinist?**

---

Hint:

> You don't have to anagram the entire riddle to find out the answer. I mean, what part of the puzzle are you trying to figure out anyway?

Comment: Haha I like the last part for the generalist badge... +1ed

Comment: @OmegaKrypton from [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85893/a-smuggled-list-of-ss) ;)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I like this a lot!

> It's Antonio Vivaldi - a phrase which anagrams perfectly to 'to an avid violinist'!

The title is a clue since

> These are four season(ing)s and one of Vivaldi's most famous concerto sets is 'The Four Seasons'.

Comment: Already?! This is why one must never underestimate the skills on Puzzling... congratulations! You got it! When would you like the tick? :P **edit:** oh, and glad you liked the puzzle :)

Comment: Apologies! It popped up when I was on lunch! :-) +1 (And any time that pleases you...)

Comment: You officially have over 30 upvotes! Well done! Also, a further congratulations ;) $\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @MrPie Thanking you kindly, sir! Much obliged :)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative answer to this could be:

> Jean Sibelius, the composer who as a young man aspired to be a professional violinist, since 'Avid' is the name of the developers of the Sibelius suite of notation software.

Though this ignores the clue in the title.

Comment: It additionally ignores the tag '[tag:anagram]' unfortunately, but nice attempt nevertheless, especially for your first answer on Puzzling.SE! (+1)

Comment: Make sure to check out the [*Help Center*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), incidentally, lest you do not contain much knowledge of this site and its policies. Most importantly, however, I strongly suggest you visit the [*Code of Conduct*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/conduct) in order for you to positively contribute to, and thus strengthen, this community. Hope you enjoy, and as they say, "Happy Puzzling!" :D